# How to exclude files using ls?

Tags: bash, ls

I'm using a python script I wrote to take some standard input from `ls` and load the data in the files described by that path. It looks something like this:

```
    ls -d /path/to/files/* | python read_files.py
```

The files have a certain name structure based on what data they have in them but are all stored in the same directory. The files I want to use have the name structure `A<fileID>_###.txt` (where `###` is always some 3 digit number). I can accomplish getting only the files that start with A by just changing what I have above slightly to `ls -d /path/to/files/A*`. HOWEVER, some files have a suffix flag called B (so the file looks like `A<fileID>_###B.txt`) and I DO NOT want to include those.

So, my question is, is there a way to exclude those files that end in `...B.txt` (or a way to only include files that end in a number)? I thought about something to the effect of:

```
    ls -d /path/to/file/R*%d.txt
```

to only include files that end in a number followed by the file extension, but couldn't find any documentation on anything of the sort.

Comment: It would be more useful if your python script accepted a list of files as arguments, rather than passing them via standard input. This would enable you to use a solution using extended globs.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Do you have to use `ls`?  With [`find`](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/find1.html), you could use the `-regex` option and also logical combinations of patterns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try this : `ls A*[^B].txt`

Comment: Worked perfectly, accomplished exactly what I asked, and didn't have to change anything I had already done is why I marked this as accepted answer

Comment: Is this shell specific.  I have files, some with underscores: 510 ==> ls lib/Inventory/*[^_]* | wc
     224     226    7495
~/webwork/sftf
511 ==> ls lib/Inventory/* | wc
     224     226    7495

Answer (score 2):

With [extended globbing](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing).

```
shopt -s extglob
ls R*!(B).txt
```